# How to create click event handler for a dynamic 2D array of buttons in C#

Tags: c#, project

I need to generate a 2D "card" of buttons dynamically. How would I go about giving each one an event handler and being able to reference the button directly?

```
public void generateButtonsCard(Panel cardPanel)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y <= 4; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= 4; x++)
            {
                cardButtons[x, y] = new Button();
                cardButtons[x, y].Size = new Size(80, 80);
                cardButtons[x, y].Name = "btn" + x + "" + y;
                cardButtons[x, y].Location = new Point(80 * x, 80 * y);
                cardPanel.Controls.Add(cardButtons[x, y]);

            }

        }

        RNGCard();
        cardButtons[2, 2].Text = "Free Space";

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dynamically creating buttons then you should dynamically create the event handlers. Creating a `void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` goes against good OO design - you want to encapsulate code and not leave it out there for any code to call.

Here's how:

```
public void generateButtonsCard(Panel cardPanel)
{
    for (int y = 0; y <= 4; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x <= 4; x++)
        {
            var button = new Button();
            button.Size = new Size(80, 80);
            button.Name = "btn" + x + "" + y;
            button.Location = new Point(80 * x, 80 * y);
            button.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                /* Your event handling code here
                   with full access to `button` above */
            };
            cardPanel.Controls.Add(button);
            cardButtons[x, y] = button;
        }
    }
    RNGCard();
    cardButtons[2, 2].Text = "Free Space";
}
```

The handler is encapsulated within the `generateButtonsCard` method and you have full access to the `button` instance within the handler. It's neat and tidy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public void generateButtonsCard(Panel cardPanel)
{
    for (int y = 0; y <= 4; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x <= 4; x++)
        {
            cardButtons[x, y] = new Button();
            cardButtons[x, y].Size = new Size(80, 80);
            cardButtons[x, y].Name = "btn" + x + "" + y;
            cardButtons[x, y].Location = new Point(80 * x, 80 * y);
            cardButtons[x, y].Click += btn_Click;
            cardPanel.Controls.Add(cardButtons[x, y]);

        }

    }

    RNGCard();
    cardButtons[2, 2].Text = "Free Space";

}

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){   
        Button b = sender as Button;
        //if (b.Name == "1")
        //{
            label1.Text = b.Name.ToString();
        //}
}
```

Result;

[image]

At Click event, sender represents the button. You can check your random variables with button's properties like commented area. (In result image there is not if condition btw.)

Hope helps,

Comment: I see. Now what if for instance I want to check if one of the button's names is equal to that of the random number generator? Normally if a button was created statically, I would write inside of the code something along the lines of

if(Buttonx.Name == RNG.toString())
{
MessageBox.Show("There is a match!");
}

But what would I do in this situation?

Comment: @Mr.AwfulAtProgramming Check updated code please. Hope it is clear.

Comment: @Mr.AwfulAtProgramming - It sounds like you're asking a follow up question. If so you should post a new question, not just tack it on to an existing answer.

Comment: Okay, this works. So I am able to, for instance, disable the button when it is pressed. However, how can I trace the exact array position in the 2D array? Specifically, lets say I am trying to set a specific cell in an array to false based on the location of the button on another array.

Comment: @Berkay I am completely new to this forum as a user. If it's an easy question would you mind answering it for me please?

Comment: Wait, this code clearly shows it. Sorry about that. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score -2):

So you can create a single button click event handler, and inside that handler you can switch your logic based on *which* button was clicked.  Here is an example of how to do it:

```
public class XYButton : Button
{
    private int xPos;
    private int yPos;

    public XYButton(int x, int y)
    {
        xPos = x;
        yPos = y;
    }

    public int GetX()
    {
        return xPos;
    }

    public int GetY()
    {
        return yPos;
    }
}
```

Then using this new extension of button...

```
public void generateButtonsCard(Panel cardPanel)
{
    for (int y = 0; y <= 4; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x <= 4; x++)
        {
            cardButtons[x, y] = new XYButton(x,y);
            cardButtons[x, y].Size = new Size(80, 80);
            cardButtons[x, y].Name = "btn" + x + "" + y;
            cardButtons[x, y].Location = new Point(80 * x, 80 * y);
            cardButtons[x, y].Click += btn_Click;
            cardPanel.Controls.Add(cardButtons[x, y]);

        }

    }

    RNGCard();
    cardButtons[2, 2].Text = "Free Space";

}

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
   var xyButton = sender as XYButton;
   // now you can get the x and y position from xyButton.
}
```

Comment: Not sure why the need for a new derived class

Comment: @MickyD for convenience and indicating code intent. So you can easily tell *which* button was clicked rather than having to parse some string button name value.  I think you could also use attributes... but I personally prefer to extend Button.

Comment: Check out the **Tag** property